# Может ли один клиент создать больше одного ws подключения с одним и тем же сервером?

Tags: websocket

Пишу свой WS сервер, и по каким то причинам, при создании с браузера второго ws соединения начинаются ошибки чтения и отправления данных
Можно ли с одного клиента создавать два вс содеинения?

Comment: Можно. Ошибки наверное от того что сервер использует общий контекст для этих соединений

Comment: @eri, как это "общий контекст"?)

Comment: @eri, соединения обрабатываются в разных потоках и данные пишутся в разыне дескрипторы.

Comment: На чем пишешь сервер?

Comment: @eri, пишу на с++, для распораллеливания использую thred

Comment: @eri, если честно, первый раз слышу фразу "общий контекст", буду рад, если вы объясните что это

Comment: @eri, щас проверил, будет ли работать, если разбивать на разные процессы с помощью fork и в основном процессе закрывать новый дескриптор, так работает, но учитывая логику сервера, разные адрессные пространства буду мешать